# Auth object Null despite successful a auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have following code in index.js and (necessary **config** = {...}) object
I am running this as node index.js and my Auth object Null despite a successful auth

```
app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
fstore = firebase.firestore()

collection = fstore.collection('issue');



auth = firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("Pappu@example.com", "secretPassword")
  .then((creds) =>  {
    console.log(creds.user.uid) ;
}) ;
```

Despite above call successful - Auth object is not available

```
var user = app.auth().currentUser ;
console.log("Try - current user")
console.log(user) ;
console.log("DONE try  - current user")
```

Comment: This is nodejs program ; not in browser

Answer (score 2):

Auth object might not yet be available when your second code snippet executes. 
Try adding authenticated state observer to know when the auth state changes, and have access to the user object:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    var uid = user.uid;

  }
});
```

This code should be placed before actual authentication.

Comment: Andrii - Thanks; your solution worked ; Does this mean all my further calls must be wrapped in onAuthStateChanged ?

Comment: If you want to handle the user object properly, then yes.